# Adding mongo to path in OS X

Tags: macos, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Bit of a noob question. I have downloaded MongoDb and installed it here

```
/Users/mike/downloads/mongodb
```

In order to start it, I then have to 'cd' into the 'bin'

```
/Users/mike/downloads/mongodb/bin
```

and run

```
./mongod  (to start the database)
```

and

```
./mongo (to start the mongo shell)
```

The problem is that I can only work with python and ruby scripts using the mongo shell if I have those scripts stored in the same bin directory, and I don't think  that's the ideal set up.

Will exporting the path allow me to access mongo from outside the bin? For example, I would prefer to have my ruby scripts in /sites/ruby and be able to access mongo by starting ruby in /sites/ruby. If exporting to path is the solution, how do I do that. I'm using a mac

Comment: Yes, you have to export the path, see linked question for Linux/OS X. Simple `export PATH=/Users/mike/downloads/mongodb/bin:$PATH` should do, when added to `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Right where it says *Possible Duplicate:* in your question :)